# Enemy AI Reacts To Player

Tags: python

I'm making a horror game using Blender, but there's just one code I struggle with.The code is how to make an enemy follow you, but stop when looked at by the player's camera. I'm pretty sure this action is done using Python scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Without Python, you can have a steering - 'path following' logic brick to target your player.
A ray/near sensor from the players eyes that detects the enemy can then toggle a (boolean) property that sets the state of the enemy to follow or not.

Like the Weeping Angels from Dr. Who, your enemy would only move when they are not looked at.